# Rewrite rule to an other domain keeping rest of url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is what I need to do:

website EXAMPLE with url

```
/?VVWM=$59095-K9T-50U00-VX0U**|jDDQvcZbTESbGqI2AJ8Iww|dIWecCGiGUive6I2AJ8Iww||||1|0$&utm_source=followup-offerte&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=VVWM
```

has to redirect to:

```
http://www.sluitsnel.nl/goedkope-scooterverzekering/?VVWM=$59095-K9T-50U00-VX0U**|jDDQvcZbTESbGqI2AJ8Iww|dIWecCGiGUive6I2AJ8Iww||||1|0$&utm_source=followup-offerte&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=VVWM
```

So the indication for this redirection is:

`http://www.goedkope-scooterverzekeringen.nl/?VVWM=$59095-K9T-50U00-VX0U`

Thanks in advcance!

Greetings,
Ivar

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?goedkope-scooterverzekeringen\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+\?(VVWM=$59095-K9T-50U00-VX0U[^\s]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.sluitsnel.nl/goedkope-scooterverzekering/?%1 [R=301,L,NE]
```